# AntDesign Table not rendering new value

Tags: reactjs, antd

My Page structure

```
Main Page - (Data is Fetch from server)
- Employee Page - (Data is then appended via file upload)
  - Employee Page Detail - (Receives data from props)
```

Employee Page constructor

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            testDataSource: props.data,
            dataSource: props.data,
        }
    }
```

Rendering Employee Page Detail

```
<FormItem>
     {getFieldDecorator('employeeDetail', {
           rules: [{required: true, message: 'Detail cannot be empty'}],
           initialValue: dataSource.employeeDetail
     })(
           <EmployeeDetailPage form={form} />
     )}
</FormItem>
```

Employee Page Detail constructor

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: props.value
        }
    }
```

then render the Table

```
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={value} />
```

I tried printing the value, on the Employee Page Detail, and its updated but somehow my table is not showing the latest value. I wonder what is wrong with this approach.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that table's data is passed by the Employee Page? If so, try to change`props.value` to `this.props.value`